# ListView content mixed up when scrolling

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I'm trying to List some data from my sql database, but when I scroll (up or down) the list gets mixed up, the data is rigth but in differente position and if I click on the item, it automaticaly changes the value to the rigth one...

This is my Interactions.xaml code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="OficinaDigitalX.Views.Interactions"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OficinaDigitalX">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel.CarInteractions/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InteractionsList, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="Fatura" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <Label Text="Intervenção" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Label Text="Total" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                       
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Invoice}"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" FontSize="10"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Article}"
                            TextColor="#503026" FontSize="10" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Total,StringFormat='{0} €'}"
                            TextColor="#503026" FontSize="10" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

this is my Interactions.xaml.cs code

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Interactions : ContentPage
{
    public Interactions (CarInfo car)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new CarInteractions(car.VehicleId);
    }
    public Interactions()
    {

    }
}
```

}

CarInteractions(car.VehicleId) returns a list that is shown on the listView

This is my CarInteractions.cs file

```
public class CarInteractions : ViewModelBase
{

    private List<InteractionsInfo> _InteractionsList;

    public List<InteractionsInfo> InteractionsList
    {
        get
        {
            return _InteractionsList;
        }

        set
        {
            _InteractionsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("InteractionsList");
        }
    }

    public CarInteractions(int id)
    {
        GetFirstInteractionRow(id);
    }

    public CarInteractions() { }

   public void GetFirstInteractionRow(int id)
    {
        string command = "(**not important**)";
        string requestUriString = $"{MainPage.server}{command}/{id}";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                InteractionsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<InteractionsInfo>>(responseString.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {

            }
            throw;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You should only set the BindingContext` in both code and XAML try removing the XAML part and see if that works for you! `<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel.CarInteractions/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>` And if this changes nothing please include the `CarInteractions.cs` file

Comment: so, i've removed the <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel.CarInteractions/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext> part and add the CarInteractions file but it didn't work either! :(

Comment: Wait I asked you to add the here `CarInteractions.cs` On Stack, where did you add it? somewhere in your code?

Comment: sorry i was uploding it! I've edited the question

Comment: First of all change the `List<InteractionsInfo>` to an `ObservableCollection<InteractionsInfo>`, don't worry it won't change your code somehow both of them are `Enumerable`

Comment: Why do you use `TwoWay` binding for your ItemsSource?

Comment: G.hakim done but still not working...

HHLV i've tryed all of them but it's the same

Comment: remove the two way binding aswell from the ItemsSource

Comment: i've removed it, nothing changed..

Comment: set this in your list `HasUnevenRows = "true"`

Comment: I've already tryed that also... Not working either

Comment: this is really weird... I have no clue why this is happening... it's like, i scroll down, sometimes the last item is the same as the first... and I click there and it change for the value that it's supposed to be there... and i scroll up again and the first item is different, sometimes the second is different too, and if I continue scrolling up and down it continues changing to different values.. the values are rigth but they weren't supposed to be in that position... And when you click it changes back to the rigth value...

Comment: What version of XF(Xamarin.Forms) do you have?

Comment: @bifedefrango can you show us how are you filling InteractionsList

Comment: @G.hakim the latest stable 3.5.0.129452

Comment: @Scarnet i've updated the Question

Comment: Did you try the v3.4 and was it working before you updated to this? As I am facing some issues with v3.5 and I am planning to add them together to GitHub and maybe this is one of them.

Comment: I haven't because I've already started with this version... I'll try 3.4 and I'll tell you in a sec

Comment: That's it @G.hakim!!!!! I've changed the XF version to 3.4 and It solved the problem!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem i am adding it as an answer kindly mark it as correct for others to find out

Comment: Also if you have any images for the issue kindly add it here i am raising an issue in Github

Comment: To Mark the answer as correct you need to click on the Right Mark that is below the voting counter, and only you can mark it as correct so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been facing some issues with XF version 3.5 that was recently released and I would suggest you roll back your XF version to 3.4 for now until these bugs are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Me as well but just now I updated to the new XF and it worked perfectly.